# How to detect a cancel out of Facebook Javascript SDK's mobile iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using Facebook Javascript SDK version 2.6 with the new 'mobile_iframe' parameter to share content (I assume it's a new param, I hadn't seen it prior to the release of 2.6 but it doesn't appear anywhere in FB's changelog). The param works as advertised, except if the user closes the dialog without sharing (i.e. cancels the mobile iframe popup) there's no way to discern by the response data that they did so.

JS:

```
myJsClass.shareDetails = {
  method: 'share',
  href: shareURL
};

if (true === [on a mobile device]) {
  myJsClass.shareDetails['mobile_iframe'] = true;
}

console.info('Share Data: ' + myJsClass.shareDetails )

FB.getLoginStatus( function( response ) {
  if ( response.authResponse )
  {
    FB.ui( myJsClass.shareDetails,
    function( response )
    {
      console.info('Response: 'response);
...
```

- On Mobile device (using mobile safari):
  Share Data: {method: "share", href: "https://[my url is here]", mobile_iframe: true, version: "v2.6"}

-- After a valid share:
Response: []

-- After a cancel:
Response: []

- On a desktop browser (using chrome):

-- After a valid share:
Response: []

-- After a cancel:
Response: {error_code: 4201, error_message: "User canceled the Dialog flow"}

Is there no way to determine a cancel out of the mobile_iframe?
For reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#mobile-web-share-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a valid bug - confirmed by Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/257808294557601

Hopefully they'll plug the hole soon.